# Automating repetitive Sweave code

Tags: r, automation, latex, knitr, sweave

In my Sweave file I will have this same block of code repeat multiple times:

```
<<tab.r,results=tex, echo=FALSE>>=
tableInstance <- getTable(first1,second)
latex(tableInstance,file = "",rowname=NULL,longtable=TRUE,dec=4,center='centering',caption="test", lines.page=4000)
@
\newpage
<<tab.r,results=tex, echo=FALSE>>=
tableInstance <- getTable(first2,second)
latex(tableInstance,file = "",rowname=NULL,longtable=TRUE,dec=4,center='centering',caption="test", lines.page=4000)
@
\newpage
<<tab.r,results=tex, echo=FALSE>>=
tableInstance <- getTable(first3,second)
latex(tableInstance,file = "",rowname=NULL,longtable=TRUE,dec=4,center='centering',caption="test", lines.page=4000)
@
\newpage
```

***Before*** this block of code, I will define `first1,first2,first3,second`, by doing, for example:

```
<<tab.r,results=tex, echo=FALSE>>=
first1 <- "FirstCondition1"
first2 <- "FirstCondition2"
first3 <- "FirstCondition3"
second <- "SecondCondition"
@
```

What I want to know is how to get the massive block of code above in some kind of function (either `R` or `LaTeX`) so I don't have to repeat it 10 times in my document? Ideally, it would be some kind of function where the arguments would be `first1,first2,first3,second` and the massive block of code won't need to be pasted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you're just asking for how to write a function?

```
<<tab.r1,results=tex, echo=FALSE>>=
myfun <- function(a,b){
    tableInstance <- getTable(a,b)
    latex(tableInstance,file = "",
          rowname=NULL,longtable=TRUE,dec=4,center='centering',
          caption="test", lines.page=4000)
}
myfun(first1,second)
@
\newpage
<<tab.r2,results=tex, echo=FALSE>>=
myfun(first2,second)
@
\newpage
<<tab.r3,results=tex, echo=FALSE>>=
myfun(first3,second)
@
\newpage
```

Note: You shouldn't use duplicate chunk names, so I've changed them.

Comment: Thanks. We can do even better (but this is good), by using a for loop over a list of the `first` variables, and using `cat('\\newpage')` at the end of each iteration, and using your `myfun` inside that loop.